# Conditional grouping with new Variable

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have the dataset

### |ID |

| 1 |
| 1   |
| 1    |
| 1   |
| 2    |
| 2   |
| 2   |

I want to create a new variable where I add all the rows with the same ID number. It should look like

| ID | New |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

Because I have four 1s, and three 2s.

Comment: With `dplyr` you could use `add_count(ID)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% summarise(n = n(), .by = ID)

  ID n
1  1 4
2  2 3

# or, if you want duplicates:

df %>% mutate(n = n(), .by = ID)

  ID n
1  1 4
2  1 4
3  1 4
4  1 4
5  2 3
6  2 3
7  2 3
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4), rep(2,3))) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new=n())`